# How to give background color to selected x-axis label in highcarts gantt

Tags: highcharts

I am using the highcharts render function to highlight and give background color to the labels using the below line of code. I was able to highlight the labels but not succeeded in giving background color.

```
chart.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.childNodes.forEach(function(label) {
       var child = label.childNodes;
       var date  = new Date(child[1].textContent).getDate();
       var day = new Date(child[1].textContent).getDay();
       if (day == 0 || (day == 6 && ((date >= 8 && date <= 14) || (date >= 22 && date <= 28))))  // if day is second Saturday or Sunday
       {
           label.style.fill = 'red';
           label.style['font-weight'] = 900;
           label.style.backgroundCOlor = 'black',  // Not working 
       }
 })
```

[I want to give background color to columns of 28 & 29 Dec as they are weekends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bV3SG.png)

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bFvZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **plotBands** feature to get this effect on the xAxis.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lnadc1sz/

```
plotBands: [{
    from: today + day * 5,
  to: today + day * 8,
}]
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/xAxis.plotBands

Comment: This has solved my question, but how the box containing the x-axis label can be given background color ?

Comment: It's impossible to set the background color to axis labels from the API level, because they are rendered as a text, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/2spj1wht/. However, I managed a workaround in which rectangles are rendered as a background, see: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4eh02wzn/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The xAxis object does not have the attribute backgroundColor.
Alternative:
try to use `labels.formatter` with background and `useHTML` flag? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/AeV7h/

```
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Foobar'],

        labels: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return '<span class="hc-label">' + this.value + '</span>';
            }
        }
    },
```

And CSS:

```
.hc-label {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Any alternate solution for this.

Comment: This will be useful if someone wants to highlight the label, not for giving background color to the div.